# Add JSON routes for all routes to handle backend requests

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and am building a service that can be seen as JSON or HTML. This approach is already done by sites like reddit.
**Example**
Normal view: http://www.reddit.com/r/soccer
JSON view: http://www.reddit.com/r/soccer.json

As you can see, they simply add `.json` to an URL and the user is able to see the exact same content either as HTML or as JSON.

I now wanted to reproduce the same in Laravel, however I'm having multiple issues.

**Approach 1 - Optional parameter**

The first thing I tried was adding optional parameter to all my routes

```
Route::get('/{type?}', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('pages/{type?}', 'PageController@index');
```

However, the problem I was facing here, is that all routes were caught by the HomeController, meaning `/pages/?type=json` as well as `/pages?type=json` were redirected to the HomeController.

**Approach 2 - Route Grouping with Namespaces**

Next I tried to add route groupings with namespaces, to seperate backend and frontend

```
Route::get('pages', 'PageController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'json', 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function(){
    Route::get('pages', 'PageController@index');
});
```

However, this doesn't work either. It does work, when using `api` as prefix, but what I want, is that I can add `.json` to every URL and get the results as json. How can I achieve that in Laravel?

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Hey, I'm using the Laravel version 5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can apply **regular expressions** on your parameters to avoud such catch-all situation as you have for **HomeController@index**:

```
Route::get('/pages{type?}', 'PageController@index'->where('type', '\.json'));
```

This way it **type** will only match, if it is equal to **.json**.

Then, to access it in your controller:

```
class PageController {
  public function index($type = null) {
    dd($type);
  }
}
```

and go to **/pages.json**

Comment: Unfortuentely this will only work like when I have the URL like this `pages?type=.json` And not like this `pages.json`. Also I would like to have it for all routes at once, without adding it for every route if it's possible. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Not true. it won't work with ?type=.json as query parameters (the ones after ?) are not considered when matching with the route.

Comment: What if you define the second route as 'pages{type?}'?

Comment: That's strange, I copied your approach into my project

`Route::get('/{type?}', 'HomeController@index')->where('type', '\.json');
Route::get('pages/{type?}', 'PageController@index')->where('type', '\.json');`, but when I access the site like this `/.json` or `/pages.json` and am outputting the type like this `dd($this->request->get('type'));` I'm getting null. However, when accessing the site like `/?type=.json` the type is `.json`.

Comment: When I define it as `pages{type?}` I'm having the same "issue". The only gets recognized If I'm using it as `type=.json`

Comment: You need to add $type as your controller's method argument - see the updated answer

Comment: Awesome. That works. I'll upvote your answer. However, before I'm accepting it: What about having this as default? Meaning, I don't want to `{type?}` and `->where('type', '\.json'));` to every route. How can I do this automatically? Also, If I have a Controller from which the PageController extends. Why can't I access `$type`  in the constructor? I would prefer if I could do this in the constructor and not in every single controller method! If you can answer this, I'll gladly accept your answer

Comment: if you dont want to update the routing easiest waybis to just use ?type=json in the URL AS it doesnt impact how routes are matched. You will have that value available in all your controller with Input::get('type')

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have done it before, but I think that's ugly :p. Honestly, there just HAS to be a way to make all routes that end with `.json` respond to a different namespace, right?

Comment: You can translate .json to ?type=json using servers rewrites to make it invisible to users OR use laravel middleware to handle that -any preferences?

Comment: That is actually a pretty good idea. That way I could use `route groups`! I could group everything with `/api` and then, if there is `.json` at the end just put '/api` in front of it, correct? So that way, `pages.json` would go to `api/pages`. That way the route group would catch that and api methods would be caught! Right?